# Form events not fired when other control is in place

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that contains a form with multiple controls.

I have subscribed to the form mouse up event. However when I click on the form if thewre is an other control placed on the form the event is not fired.

So, I would like to capture an form event on the form (even when an control is in place). Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check my answer and tell me if it is okay :)

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF or ??? You should tag your question so it's easy to know.

Comment: Please tell us what do you expect and why my answer doesn't suit you ?! Some guy try to help you and you have 0 response ?!

Comment: Your form will have to implement IMessageFilter and call Application.AddMessageFilter() to see the mouse messages before the control does.  If this sounds awkward then you'd be partway to understanding why you should not really do this.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I will continue working on the project today.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know windows forms doesn't implement the concept of event bubbling. So you should manually tweak controls to handle the event. You can do it manually looping through all controls, or you can create some kind of wrapper for your form/container to subscribe to the event automatically. You may check general implementation of this idea [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9ec81c19-7465-47a6-9c85-a87c1fa5e949/capture-mouse-move-in-container-control?forum=winforms). .